# Proofs that the zero vector is not linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Re-checking my linear algebra, using Lax textbook *Linear algebra and its applications*.

I want to know if my attempt of proving the following theorem it's ok (it has been a while since I attended this lecture).

> Show that if the vectors $x_1, x_2,\dots,x_j$ are linearly independent, then
>   none of them is the zero vector.

As far as I understand, this is a proof by contradiction. I have to exhibit a
nontrivial linear combination that fulfills

$$
k_1x_1+k_2x_2+\dots+k_jx_j=0,
$$

where $k_j\in K$ are elements in the field $K$.

Without loss of generality, suppose that $x_1$ is the zero vector. Then

$$
k_1x_1+\dots+k_jx_j=0,
$$

where all the $k_i$ must be zero. We can sum on both sides the term $\tilde{k}x_1$ (where $\tilde{k}\in K$), and by Eq. (10): $0x_1=0$. Therefore

$$
(\tilde{k}+k_1)x_1+\dots+k_jx_j=\tilde{k}x_1+\dots+k_jx_j=0,
$$

and I have showed that there is a non-trivial linear combination with the zero vector, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I don't really understand this - what is $\overline{k}$? This is much more complicated than it needs to be (we can explicitly write down a nontrivial linear combination equaling zero ...).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, as it stands, this is not a good proof.

- You don't every introduce your assumption. You are assuming that the set *is* linearly independent, and that is why you can conclude something about $k_i$.
- You don't say what $\overline{k}$ is; you need $\overline{k}$ to be non-zero, or else you've concluded nothing.
- The proof is pretty circuitous and comes to the correct conclusion in a very roundabout way.

The key idea is just your last line: exhibit a combination that has a non-zero coefficient. Taking $k_1 = 1$ and $k_i = 0$ for $i > 1$ is good enough. And this gives a proof by contrapositive, which is quite a bit cleaner than the contradiction proof you were going for.

Comment: The set is linearly independent. That is given. I bought you the $\tilde{k}$, but to say it's not defined is a little bit pedantic. The proof is long because this is what usually happens when one is learning math, first long proofs, then hone the results and after synthesize

Comment: @user2820579 You never introduced $\overline{k}$! Is it a real number, is it zero, is it something else? This is an important thing - you need to introduce your variables and say what they are before using them; after all, as I pointed out, if $\overline{k} = 0$ you cannot draw the conclusion that you want. It is also very important, especially for students who are just learning how to prove things for the first time, to *clearly* include their assumptions and techniques; the reader shouldn't come to the end of the proof and be surprised it's a contradiction.

Comment: If someone would explain the reason for the downvote, I would really appreciate it so I can improve the answer. OP asked for critique of their proof and I gave it (pinging @user2820579 if you have any other comments...).

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I understand, this is a proof by contradiction. I have to
>   exhibit a nontrivial linear combination that fulfills
>
> $$ k_1x_1+k_2x_2+\dots+k_jx_j=0, $$
>
> where $k_j\in K$ are elements in the field $K$.

So far so good.

> Without loss of generality, suppose that $x_1$ is the zero vector.
>   Then
>
> $$ k_1x_1+\dots+k_jx_j=0, $$
>   where all the $k_i$ must be zero.

No, no, stop the bus here.  You just correctly stated your goal: you have to *exhibit* the $k_i$.  That is:  you have to come up with explicit values to assign to them.  In this case set $k_1 = 1$, $k_2 = k_3 = \cdots = k_j = 0$ and you are done.  Then the *contradiction* is that this is a nontrivial linear combination, contradicting the assumed linear independence.

This is actually more cleanly done by the proving the *contrapositive*: "If one of $x_i$ is $0$ then $\{x_1, \ldots, x_j\}$ is not a linearly independent set."  Then you can give a direct proof of that statement rather than having to come up with a contradiction.  The contrapositive is always equivalent to the original statement.

Comment: (+1); this is a nice clean explanation that shows why the setup for the contradiction wasn't correct in the posting.

Comment: @user296602 Thanks.  I've found that in beginning proofs like these, at least 50% of the errors are due to basic confusion about logic, like the difference in how to prove $\forall$ statements vs. $\exists$ statements etc.  Once they have the basic proof-outline in place it's easy to fill in the "actual math" bits.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$. I guess it suffices to prove that if $v$ is the zero vector, then $\lambda v = 0_{V}$ for all $\lambda \in K$. Then, for $v_1, ..., v_n \in V$, if $v_i$ is the zero vector:
$$\lambda_1 v_1 + ... + \lambda_i v_i + ... + \lambda_n v_n = 0_V $$

is a non-trivial combination for $ \lambda_1 = ... = \lambda_{i-1} = \lambda_{i+1} = ... = \lambda_n = 0_K $ and any non-zero $\lambda_i \in K$.

To see that $\lambda 0_v = 0_V$ for all $\lambda$, see that $\lambda 0_V = \lambda (0_V + 0_V) = \lambda 0_V + \lambda 0_V$. Applying the inverse of $\lambda 0_V$ in both sides of the equation - which exists by the axioms of vector spaces - we get $\lambda 0_V = 0_V$.